# How to insert multiple rows of data, some of which have multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert multiple rows of data from select2 fields. Some of the fields in the rows may have multiple selections. My code works with just one row of data and one field having multiple selections as shown in the picture below. But with multiple rows, the insertion does not work as expected. Please good folks, I need your help.

```
public function save_staff()
{
$subjects = count($this->input->post('subject'));
   $names = count($this->input->post('names'));
  if($names > 0){
    for($i=0; $i < $names; $i++){

         for($p=0; $p < $subjects; $p++){

    $names_array = array(
        'names' => $this->input->post('names')[$i],
        'sign' => $this->input->post('sign')[$i],
        'subject' => $this->input->post('subject')[$p]

    );
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $names_array);

}
}
```

[image: Screenshot of insertion form]

The code above works with just one row of data. And the data in the database is normalized as shown in the second image.[image: Screenshot of inserted data]. Adding another row of data  with one field having multiple selections like the first, my code cannot handle it. How can I adjust code to get it right? The third image captures a screenshot of what my code can't handle.[image: screenshot of scenario that my code can't handle]

Comment: cooltoad's active record has an `insert_batch()` function

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this on your input:

```
<select name="subject[][]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
```

Controller:

```
$a1 = $this->input->post('subject');
$count1 = count($a1);

for ($i=0; $i < $count1 ; $i++) {

        $count2 = count($a1[$i]);

        if(!empty($count2)){
            for ($j=0; $j < $count2 ; $j++) {
                $names_array = array(
                    'subject' => $a1[$i][$j]

                );
            $this->db->insert($names_array);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

what does you $this->db->insert() function look like ?

you will probably need to reformat it to follow this:

```
INSERT INTO  table_name
(
    col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3
)
VALUES
(                    <--- first record being added
    'test',
    'someValue',
    2
),
(                   <--- second record being added
    'test_theSecond',
    'someValue',
    1234
);
```